# Cannot update McAfee

Tags: windows-7, updates, anti-virus

Trying to update McAfee (SaaS Endpoint Protection 5.2.0) manually via clicking Update Now from the taskbar icon (Windows 7). Get the following message

> Unable to create Cab Installer Object. Agent Service may not be running properly.

Does anyone know how to proceed? Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did this EVER work?  Have you tried a reinstall of McAfee?  Which edition/version of McAfee?

Comment: I think for a while it was updating automatically, then Security Center Communication stated that last update agent failed and that I should run a manual update, then the manual produced that error message. I was hoping there was a more direct way then reinstalling it. It's McAfee SaaS Endpoint Protection 5.2.0.

Comment: Well a re-install may be in order, and while you're at it, you may want to look into updating to 'v5.2 patch 3' (5.2.3, or higher, if it's available to you).  What exactly have you tried so far? Reboot? Tried anything from McAfee's KB?  Called McAfee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you confirmed all McAfee services are running?  Simply run Services.msc and check the list.  Right click to start if you find a McAfee service taht is stopped.

Check event logs as well to see if there is more detailed information there.

Comment: All the McAfee services are listed as started. Where do I find the event logs?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer

Comment: @Dave M:  Ooooh, that's a sneaky looking name for a web page -- it's about "Event Viewer" (and how to open it, so +1 for your comment), not an open-source Event Viewer.  I wonder if Microsoft did this by accident?